# AWS Lambda deployment issue using zappa

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm using tensorflow and ImageAI in my python code, but when trying to upload it on Lambda getting following warning:

```
Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.
```

It's successfull and working when I removed this line from my code:
from imageai.Prediction.Custom import CustomImagePrediction

I have created virtual environment and uploaded package on lambda using zappa, but no success

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    from imageai.Prediction.Custom import CustomImagePrediction
    import os
    filename = 'Image path'
    prediction = CustomImagePrediction()
    prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
    prediction.setModelPath("Model path")
    prediction.setJsonPath("Model json path")
    prediction.loadModel(num_objects=7)
    predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(filename, result_count=3)
    data = {}
    for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
        data[eachPrediction] = eachProbability
    return jsonify({"status":"200","message": "Ok"})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=False)
```

> Expected Result: Your updated Zappa deployment is live!:
>   https://i8ppr4snid.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

```
Actual Result: Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.
```

Comment: `zappa tail` your logs and see if you get more details on the actual error.

Comment: I have tried same and get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Comment: You get any error during build? you have `imageai` in your requirements.txt ? seems like a missing dependency issue

Comment: @Ravish Thanks for your reply. I got this error at the time of deployment. I have already installed all the required library in **virtual environment**. I have also tried with including **imageai** in requirement.txt but no success.

Comment: you can check the zip Artifact that Zappa uploads to S3 bucket during deployment. Verify this zip to confirm you have the *imageai* module inside the zip. 

There are 2 possibility: 1) imageai is not bundled in your Zeppa package deployed to Lambda, 2) imageai (like tesseract) requires some binary module and can't work outof the box with Lambda

Comment: @Ravish I have checked and imageAI is available inside zip file. How can we sort out point 2?